# iCloud folders visible in Finder but not in 'file upload' dialog in Safari, how to enable this?

Tags: macos, icloud, finder, safari, mojave

MacOS 10.14.6 (Mojave) / Safari 14.0.3

In Finder I can see the following section and folders in the sidebar:

iCloud

- iCloud drive
- Documents
- Desktop

[image]

However, if I open safari, go to a site where I can upload a file and look at the pop up/finder-style window, that whole 'iCloud' sidebar section is missing (but all the other folders e.g. local HD, NAS etc are visible)

[image]

How can I upload iCloud files from Safari 14 on macOS 10.14 ?

Comment: What is the web site?

Comment: @Gilby Any website.. this website too when I was uploading the images.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to move "iCloud Drive" from "iCloud" section to "Favourites" in Finder and Safari uploader will display that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I realize the title of the question asks *"how to enable this"*. Also, the OP originally included the question *"How can I ensure it is enabled?"* at the end of the post. However user [anki](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/313842/anki) made edits which changed the question at the end of the post to *"How can I upload iCloud files from Safari 14 on macOS 10.14?"* Since user [anki](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/313842/anki) is currently offering a bounty on this post, I feel I should answer user anki's question. Besides, user anki already correctly [answered](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/413101/icloud-folders-visible-in-finder-but-not-in-file-upload-dialog-in-safari-how/414468#414468) the OP's original questions.

Here, I will make the assumption the users home folder is on the drive with the label `Macintosh HD`. Under a typical macOS installation, this would be a reasonable assumption to make. However, there exists the possibility the OP's Mac has been configured so the users home folder is on a drive that has been removed from the sidebar.

The steps to reach the `iCloud Drive` folder **from Safari** are given below.

> Note: These steps are meant to be taken from the Safari image posted by the OP. If these steps are taken from the OP's Finder image, then step 6 can probably be omitted.

1. In the sidebar, select `Macintosh HD` to view the contents.
2. Open the `Users` folder.
3. Open the your home folder. This would be the folder with house icon shown below.

   [image: house icon]
4. Open the the folder labeled `Library`. If this folder is not displayed, then press the key combination <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd><shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to show hidden files.

   > Note: You can undo the showing of hidden files by pressing the same <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd><shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> key combination. You may wish to do this after opening the `Library` folder.
5. Open the `Mobile Documents` folder.
6. Open the `iCloud Drive` folder.

I tested this procedure by uploading the house image shown above. I noticed that if I wanted to upload another image, the selection window opened to the `iCloud Drive` by default.

### How to Always Show the `Library` Folder

To avoid having to show hidden files to access the `Library` folder in the above answer, you can make this `Library` folder alway visible. The steps are given below.

1. In a `Finder` application window, open your home folder.
2. From the `Finder` menu bar, select `View`>`Show View Options` or press the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> key combination.
3. Check off the box labeled `Show Library Folder`, as shown below.

[image: preferences]

Comment: I can't do step 5 open mobile documents folder.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP1UM.png Edit actually right click > open in new tab works.

Comment: Actually, double click works too.. I'm too used to the column view.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to verify my answer by using the Finder instead of Safari. I up updated my answer to clarify the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely are 1 of these two things.

1. The 'Choose file' menu is not a default uploader and uses some kind of Java uploader or other magic. If so, that it that I guess.
2. The settings in Safari are 'corrupted'. Just remove and add the iCloud folders in your sidebar and I expect that the Safari 'Open file' window will mimic the Finder.

[image]

Comment: 1 is unlikely.. it is the native uploader I've been using on the same site for a long time. I tried 2. Yours work because the section "iCloud" (like "Tags") is visible in Safari. For me, the whole section is not there.

Comment: I think you can add the section by removing them from Finder and than adding them, just like I show in the beautiful animated GIF ;)

Comment: you moved an "item" "iCloud Drive" from a "section" "iCloud". You didn't move the section. The section is absent in my uploader.

Answer (score -1):

Within the 'Choose File' window you can go to the iCloud directory using the Finder keyboard shortcut for that. By default this is <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>

The 'Go' menu in Finder gives me the following list of shortcuts:

[image: Go menu in Finder]

Comment: Other shortcuts work, but the shortcut for iCloud doesn't work.